# wp_enqueue_scripts not calling my function

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting, styles, themes

I am thoroughly confused as to why this won't work. I have a function hooked into wp_enqueue_scripts and it doesn't seem to call my function. 
I have checked that I have both wp_head() and wp_footer() in my templates.
Heres my code:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
define( 'ML_DIR', get_template_directory() );
define( 'ML_URI', get_template_directory_uri() );

require ML_DIR . '/inc/enqueues.php';
?>
```

**inc/enqueues.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts ', 'ml_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
function ml_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'ml-bootstrap-grid-style', ML_URI . '/assets/lib/bootsrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ml-style', ML_URI . '/style.css', array( 'ml-bootstrap-grid-style' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ml-mods-style', ML_URI . '/assets/css/mods.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ml-script', ML_URI . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is showing in your html code ? js and css file wiith wrong link ? or no link at all ? I would like to suggest to check that. It may be the scripts are getting included but with wrong path.

Comment: maybe include the scripts file instead of require - also, this is the weirdest way I have ever seen enqueueing scripts.

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting error in console? If yes, then script path is not proper. Else i need to check it in detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi think one extra space is there after `'wp_enqueue_scripts '` Please remove that and try

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ml_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
function ml_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'ml-bootstrap-grid-style', ML_URI . '/assets/lib/bootsrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ml-style', ML_URI . '/style.css', array( 'ml-bootstrap-grid-style' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ml-mods-style', ML_URI . '/assets/css/mods.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ml-script', ML_URI . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. Such a dumb mistake to make, too.

Comment: Glad this helped you :)